# Range of Validity of a Number Theory Corollary

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I was going through [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/SatoNT.pdf) paper. On **Page 6**, it's written

> *Corollary 2.3.* For any positive integers $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$, $a_n$, there exist
> integers $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_n$, such that $$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n = gcd(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$$

So, I was wondering if it is true for all $n≥0$ *i.e.* is it universal, or are there any constraints?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_three_or_more_integers

Comment: That statement is clear. No constraints.

Comment: This is just Bézout's identity, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, true for all $n\geq 1$.  I don't know what you might mean for the case of $n=0$.  As for constraints, it can be used in any euclidean domain.

Comment: @JMoravitz if i have xi and ai in range [0, p) can i find all the possible permutations of xi which makes this equation a1.x1+a2.x2+⋯+an.xn divisible by p. **p** is some prime no. and ai is known

Comment: The proof shows that it is true for all naturals $n$ and all integers $a_i$. The same proof works for any Euclidean domain, i.e. a domain that enjoys division with smaller remainder, e.g. polynmials over a field.